# Sinónimo da tag "cordova" → "phonegap"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Conforme pode ser visto na explicação dada no Blog da Phonegap, o projecto está agora sob a alçada do Apache e recebeu um novo nome de "cordova".

## [PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/)

> As a result of the contribution, we were required to ensure that the intellectual property was unfettered by trademark ambiguity. This presented us with the hard requirement to rename PhoneGap in its open source form as a project incubating at Apache. The name we first choose was Apache Callback, which was dumb for a host of reasons and quickly the community renamed it to Cordova.

Que traduzido:

> Como resultado da contribuição, fomos obrigados a garantir que a propriedade intelectual não fosse negada por ambiguidade. Isto apresentou-nos com a exigência difícil de mudar o nome de PhoneGap na sua forma de código aberto como um projecto de incubação na Apache. O nome que escolhemos em primeiro foi Apache Callback, que era mudo por uma série de razões, e rapidamente a comunidade renomeou para Cordova.

Também podemos ver que no SOEN, que o [sinónimo existe](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cordova/info).

Assim sendo, sugeria a criação do sinónimo:

[phonegap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap) → [cordova](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova) ← [phonegap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap)

Comment: Criei o sinônimo no sentido oposto (phonegap é a tag principal), por considerar que o projeto tende a ser chamado de *phonegap* mesmo.